# Using a void* as a buffer to store uint_32 variables acting as RAM memory. How to read and write to it?

Tags: c, pointers, buffer

The issue I'm having is for a project that is simulating RAM memory using a void* that is allocated N number of bytes. Always multiples of 4.
One of the requirements is that is **has** to use a void*, so I'm not able to use uint_32 or char to use it.

Here is a current

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {

void* mem = malloc(4096); //allocate 4096 bytes

uint32_t* test1 = malloc(sizeof(uint32_t));
*test1=12344444;

uint32_t* test2 = malloc(sizeof(uint32_t));
*test2=56788888; //declaring some test values

memcpy(&mem, &test1, sizeof(uint32_t)); //I try to copy test1 to the start of void*
memcpy(&mem+sizeof(uint32_t), &test2, sizeof(uint32_t)); //I try to copy test2 next to test1

print(mem);
return 0;
```

}

And I made a simple print to see what is being written to the buffer.

```
void print(void* buffer){
for(int i = 0; i<4096; i+=sizeof(uint32_t)){
    printf ("%d ", *((uint32_t*)(buffer+i)));
}
```

}

The issue is that I'm getting some weird values in some of these indexes and my two tests are separated by some weird data after I do the first memcpy.

```
12344444 0 0 0 0 0 33 0 56788888
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is there another way while still using void* for the mem?
What would I need to do to access the variable stored at the nth byte?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mem and test1 are already the pointers the destination and source buffer, so do this

```
memcpy(mem, test1, sizeof(uint32_t));
```

Comment: Test1 is also a pointer

Comment: Wow, I feel so dumb. I spent so much time in that error. This fixed it! Thank you so much!